# Lord Rama's path to exile from Ayodhya in today's India

Tags: ramayana

I would like to know if we can trace a path of Lord Rama's exile journey from Ayodhya to Sri Lanka.
The towns he visited on his route.

Prominent stop overs, like Shabari visit, deer hunting location, Vaali, Sughriva.

**In the answer expecting towns of India to trace the path.**

Comment: Yes, In fact there are entire yatra tours with thousands of folks, tracing his path led by a Swami from Chennai.

Comment: To this list can be added river  crossing with Guha, Panchavati, place where Sitha's necklaces  were found, Jatayu/Sampathi episodes river Sarayu where Rama entered etc.. But the place where Rama prayed at Dhanushkodi, the Sethu bridge are well known..

Comment: Another answer found here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35133/3881

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I have gathered about the route of *Lord Rama* to Sri Lanka during his fourteen years of exile.

**Ayodhya**: The origin, this is where it all started, the *pad yatra* for exile.

**Prayagraj or Allahabad**: This is the place where three rivers  meet *Ganga*, *Yamuna* and mythic *Saraswati*, hence **Triveni Sangam**.

**Chitrakoot**:This is the place he planned to put up his tent and settle    for next fourteen years.

**Dandakaranya**: Since *Mata Sita* was abducted in Chitrakoot he went looking for her in this area, which spans across various states. It is in these forests that *Rama* and *Lakshmana* met Shabari, exact location unknown. The other stops were **Nagpur, Maharastra** and **Bhadrachalam, Telangana**.

**Hampi**: This is where *Rama* meets *Sugreeva* and vanara sena and heads to *Sri Lanka*.

**Rameswaram**: Crossing the *Ram Setu*, the vanaras build the stone bridge by placing the rocks.

**Sri Lanka**: Final destination to meet with *Sita*.

**Mapped on Google Maps**
[image: Route List]

[image: Route Map]

Comment: Great to kearn,I upvoted.Thanks

Comment: But He went to Gaya dham also so far as I know

Comment: Please cite references in your answer. Where did you get that these are the towns and places visited by Sree Rama? There could be many other places too. Visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/5212). Answers without proper references can be subjected to deletion after a period of time.

Comment: Seems to miss some locations. All versions of the Ramayana including Valmiki cite that he visited locations in Kerala such as the Pampa river and Sangamagrama, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The determined citizens of Ayodhya followed God Rama, Sita and Lakshmana to the forest up to the banks of River Tamsa. They decide to leave before the crack of dawn, when the citizens are still asleep. They cross River Tamsa and then River Gomti [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 2.45-49].

They reached the banks of River Ganga at Shringverapura, a region ruled by their friend Nishada King Guha. Then, they cross River Ganga in a sturdy boat having a rudder [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 2.50-52], driven by boatman Kevat. This is present-day Shringverpur in Uttar Pradesh state.

They reach Rishi Bharadwaja’s ashrama at the confluence of River Ganga and Yamuna, present-day Prayagraj in Uttar Pradesh state. Bharadwaja advises them to go westwards and stay at an idyllic place called Chitrakoot. Accordingly, they cross River Yamuna and travel to Chitrakoot which is on the border of present-day states of Madhya Pradesh and Uttar Pradesh [Valmiki Ramayana 2.54-56].

Later, Bharata says he will rule in God Rama’s name from the outskirts in Nandigrama, present-day Nandagaon near Ayodhya [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 2.112-115; Garuda Purana chapter 143]. Present-day Chitrakoot has caves with a Shiva-linga and big seats made of stone with intricate carvings, where God Rama stayed. Even today, one can visit locations in Chitrakoot like Rama ghat, Sita rasoi, Janaki kund and Bharat-milap temple.

From Chitrakoot, God Rama, Sita and Lakshmana visit the nearby ashrama of Rishi Atri and Anasuyadevi. The learned sage describes to God Rama that the wicked Rakshasas come from the nearby forest and prevent them from performing their Vedic rituals [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 2.117-119]. God Rama goes into the forest and kills Viradha Rakshasa. They reach Rishi Sharbhanga's ashrama [Valmiki Ramayana 3.3-5].

There is a Sati Anasuya ashrama 16 km from present-day Chitrakoot, nearby are Viradh-kund and Sharbhanga ashrama [Ref: holydham.com].

From Rishi Sharabhanga's ashrama, travelling a long way in the Dandaka forest crossing many rivers to reach Rishi Suteekshna's ashrama. Then, they pass many mountain peaks, forests, streams and rivers and lived near various ascetics for 10 years and return to Rishi Suteekshna's ashrama. From here they visit Rishi Agastya nearby [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 3.9-11].

A (truncated) Dandaka forest exists today in present-day southern Chhattisgarh state, bordering Telangana state. Many evidences of their presence are found in present-day Ramtek in Maharashtra, and Parnasala on the banks of River Godavari in Telangana state near the temple town of Bhadrachalam which is also called Dakshina Ayodhya. There is an Agastya ashrama on the banks of River Pravara at Aroli village in Akole taluka, south of Nashik. Another Agastya Rishi temple is on Ankai hill, east of Nashik.

Agastya guides them to the nearby Panchavati [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 3.13]. This is believed to be present-day Nashik in Maharashtra state having locations like Panchvati, Tapovan, Rama-kunda, Sita-gufa and Lakshmana-kunda. God Rama, Sita and Lakshmana also worship Goddess Durga at the nearby Saptashrungi temple as per local folklore.

While Ravana is flying away in the pushpaka-vimana, Sita’s cries of help are heard by the bird Jatayu who fought against Ravana. There is a Jatayu hill-temple at present-day Uddhar near Pali in Maharashtra state, believed to be his residence. Sita drops her ornaments, especially when she sees 5 monkeys sitting on a hill near Kishkindha, present-day Hampi in Karnataka state. This is to leave a trail for God Rama to find her [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 3.49-54].

It is believed that God Rama had met Jatayu at Lepakshi (meaning ‘rise bird’) village, 15 km east of present-day Hindpur in Anantapur district of Andhra Pradesh state.

The 2 brothers immediately set out in search of Sita.
As per local folklore, the extreme west location reached by the brothers is just off the sea-shore. Here, God Rama fires an arrow to obtain sweet water and worships God Shiva after making a Shiva-linga using walu (sand). Hence these places got named Banganga and Walkeshwar, in present-day Mumbai. Then they again move inland. They worship Goddess Bhavani at present-day Tuljapur in Maharashtra state.

Kavandha Rakshasa tells the 2 brothers to meet Sugreeva at Rishyamukha mountains on the banks of Pampa sarovar, which is on the outskirts of the kingdom of Kishkindha, present-day Hampi in Karnataka state [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 3.72].

[Source: 'Essence of the Fifth Veda' by Gaurang Damani pages 9, 11, 12, 23-27].